# Transformations of function not vertical/horizontal

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I do not understand how to solve these transformation of functions.
Can someone please explain how these are solved?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTysV.png

and

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbE9v.png

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your first question can be handled in the following manner:-

1. Let g(x) = (1/6)h(x) where h(x) = f(x) + 15.
2. In h(x) = f(x) + 15, h(x) is a transformation that acts on f(x) and the effect is to move the graph f(x) vertically upward by 15 units.
3. In g(x) = (C)h(x), g(x) is a transformation that acts on h(x) and the effect is to stretch (magnify) or shrink (compress) the graph of h(x) in the y-direction by a factor of (C). $C > 1$ means stretch and $0<C<1$ means compress.
4. g(x) is then the combined result of action in (2) followed by the action in (3).

Hope you can take it from here.